# What is this technique/pattern called?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, actions, technique

I'm a graphic design student in the middle of creating book covers. I'm trying to find an action or at least a tutorial on how to do the effect done in the red. Does anyone know what this is called? I've tried "scroll", "scrollwork", and "engraving" but it did not turn up any results.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

A good lesson for nearly any graphic design student is to learn how to design without leaning on software automation to do it for you. :)

That said, this couldn't be automated very well to begin with. It's simply 'design' in the sense that someone took the time to carefully draw it.

As for the particular style, it's 'art deco'...which is quite appropriate given the era of the subject matter. I'd suggest spending some time looking through art deco work to get inspiration.

Comment: Ive just had a great time looking through Pinterest and found heaps of Nouveaux and Deco work (graphic, fabric, acrhitecture and furniture - would have been created exclusively by hand by true crafts men and women, amazing time to be alive!